# eBay api search item

Tags: php, ebay-api

I want to get items by keyword search.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once("includes/config.php");

// Construct the HTTP GET call
$apicall = "https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?"; // 
URL to call
$apicall .= "q=GTR"; //search keyword
$apicall .= "limit=3"; 

// Create headers to send with CURL request.
$headers = array
(
'X-EBAY-API-APP-ID: ' . $sapp_id,
'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: ' . $dev_id,
'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: ' . $cert_id,
'X-EBAY-C-ENDUSERCTX: 5337984774'
);

// Send request to eBay and load response in $response
$connection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, 
"https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?");
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $apicall);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($connection);
curl_close($connection);
// Load the call and capture the document returned by eBay API
$resp = $response;

// Output response
echo("<pre>");

print_r($resp);
//To retrieve specific values of the array in PHP, you will need to use 
object operator
// $value = $resp->Item->ConvertedCurrentPrice;
// $value = $resp->Item->ConvertedCurrentPrice;
// print $xml->Product->Title;

echo("</pre>");

?>
```

i got this error when i run.

```
{
"errors": [
{
"errorId": 3001,
"domain": "ROUTING",
"category": "REQUEST",
"message": "Request Rejected",
"longMessage": "The Request has errors. For help, see the documentation for this API."
}
]
}
```

Since i am beginner i don't know what to do.

i tried xml request method and it's work fine but i want to do it with REST API method.

i follow this docs - [Official eBay search api documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/resources/item_summary/methods/search#h2-input)

i like to know why i am getting this error and what's the correct way to achieve this search query ?

Comment: In your line `curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, ` should you be using the value of `$apicall` that you built earlier?

Comment: The url you construct looks incorrect - it should be more like `..../search?q=GTR&limit=3` rather than `..../search?q=GTRlimit=3`??

Comment: Looking at the documentation https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/resources/methods suggests that to use the `search` method you should issue a GET request whereas your curl code is sending a POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested as I don't have an eBay developer account but perhaps the following might help. The code below will issue a GET request with the querystring as part of the url as the [documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/resources/item_summary/methods/search) suggests

```
<?php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );

    require_once("includes/config.php");

    /* 
        you can download from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
    */
    $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem'; # edit as appropriate to point to valid `cacert.pem` file
    $verbose=true;




    $endpoint = "https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?";
    $args=array(
        'q'     =>  'GTR',
        'limit' =>  3
    );
    $url=sprintf( '%s%s', $endpoint, http_build_query( $args ) );

    /*
        for advanced debug information we create a stream
        and output to that during the request. At the end 
        of the request the stream is processed and we can
        view that data.
    */
    if( $verbose )$vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');

    $headers = array(
        'X-EBAY-API-APP-ID: ' . $sapp_id,
        'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: ' . $dev_id,
        'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: ' . $cert_id,
        'X-EBAY-C-ENDUSERCTX: 5337984774'
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'curl' );

    if( $verbose ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh ); # the stream object
    }

    /* make the request and get info */
    $response = curl_exec( $curl );
    $info=(object)curl_getinfo( $curl );
    $errors=curl_error( $curl );

    /* store the verbose debug info */
    if( $verbose ){
        rewind( $vbh );
        $debug=stream_get_contents( $vbh );
        fclose( $vbh );
    }
    curl_close( $curl );




    if( $info->http_code==200 ){

        printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $response, 1 ) );

    } else{

        printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $verbose ? $debug : $info ,1 ) );
        printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $errors, 1 ) );
    }
?>
```